# Add and Sub time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

In MySQL table I have these value `00:00:00` and `06:00:00`.

I need sub three hours on `00:00:00`, return `21:00:00` and add three hours on `06:00:00`, return `09:00:00`.

I have tried this sql query, without success.

Please help me, thank you in advance.

```
mysql> SELECT
    SUBTIME('00:00:00', 3),
    ADDTIME('06:00:00', 3);
+------------------------+------------------------+
| SUBTIME('00:00:00', 3) | ADDTIME('06:00:00', 3) |
+------------------------+------------------------+
| -00:00:03              | 06:00:03               |
+------------------------+------------------------+
1 row in set

mysql>
```

**#Edit 1**

```
mysql> SELECT
    '00:00:00' - INTERVAL 3 HOUR,
    '06:00:00' + INTERVAL 3 HOUR;
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
| '00:00:00' - INTERVAL 3 HOUR | '06:00:00' + INTERVAL 3 HOUR |
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
| NULL                         | NULL                         |
+------------------------------+------------------------------+
1 row in set

mysql>
```

**#Edit 2**

```
mysql> SELECT
    DATE_ADD('00:00:00', INTERVAL 3 HOUR),
    DATE_ADD('06:00:00', INTERVAL 3 HOUR);

SELECT
    SUBTIME('00:00:00', '03:00:00'),
    ADDTIME('06:00:00', '03:00:00');
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| DATE_ADD('00:00:00', INTERVAL 3 HOUR) | DATE_ADD('06:00:00', INTERVAL 3 HOUR) |
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
| NULL                                  | NULL                                  |
+---------------------------------------+---------------------------------------+
1 row in set

+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| SUBTIME('00:00:00', '03:00:00') | ADDTIME('06:00:00', '03:00:00') |
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
| -03:00:00                       | 09:00:00                        |
+---------------------------------+---------------------------------+
1 row in set

mysql>
```

Comment: check my edited answer

Answer (score 0):

It Should be

```
SELECT
    TIME(SUBTIME(CONCAT(curdate(),' ','00:00:00'), 03:00:00)),
    TIME(ADDTIME(CONCAT(curdate(),' ','00:00:00'), 03:00:00));
```

Comment: Thanks, please see **#Edit 2** in my first question-

Answer (score 0):

Since there is actually no time like '-00:00:03', you cannot apply time operation to do such thing.

If you really need to to this, I recommend you to

1. Change the column to `INT` type, and do the operation by yourself.
2. Change the column to `DATETIME` type, and try to deal with the cross-day problem by yourself.
3. Or apply the following...

   ```
   SELECT CONCAT(
     TIMESTAMPDIFF(
       HOUR,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2015/01/01 ', '00:00:00'), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s'),
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2015/01/01 ', '00:00:00'), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s') - interval 3 hour
     ) % 24,
     ":",
     TIMESTAMPDIFF(
       MINUTE,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2015/01/01 ', '00:00:00'), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s'),
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2015/01/01 ', '00:00:00'), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s') - interval 3 hour
     ) % 60,
     ":",
     TIMESTAMPDIFF(
       SECOND,
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2015/01/01 ', '00:00:00'), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s'),
       STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT('2015/01/01 ', '00:00:00'), '%Y/%m/%d %H:%i:%s') - interval 3 hour
     ) % 60
   );
   ```

   Just replace `'00:00:00'` and `3 hour` to anything you want.

It just try to concat you time to a datetime string, and transform it into datetime then apply the interval operation. After that it apply the timediff to compute elapsed time by given unit(do not forget to % to get the correct domain). And finally concatenation the three differences.

This answer is kinda ugly, hope it is helpful to you.